# Show this subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory

I'm given a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by the inequalities as follows:

$|x_{1}|+...+|x_{r}|+2(\sqrt{x^{2}_{r+1}+x^{2}_{r+2}}+...\sqrt{x^{2}_{n-1}+x^{2}_{n}})\leq n$.

I need to show this is convex.  I'm given the hint to show the set is closed under taking midpoints then to use the inequality $\sqrt{(a+b)^{2}+(c+d)^{2}}\leq \sqrt{a^{2}+c^{2}} + \sqrt{b^{2}+d^{2}}$.

To show it is closed under midpoints would I simply show for two elements in this set $C$ we have $\frac{a+b}{2}\leq n$?

Anything to help get me started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The sum of convex functions is convex, level sets (of the form $\{x:c(x)\le n\}$) of convex functions are convex, and the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ semi-norms are convex.

Comment: Why I did not see this comment. If I see it, I would not write my answer. But... if it is written now, let it exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x_1,\dots x_n)=|x_{1}|+...+|x_{r}|+2\left(\sqrt{x^{2}_{r+1}+x^{2}_{r+2}}+...\sqrt{x^{2}_{n-1}+x^{2}_{n}}\right).$$ This is the sum of two convex functions: $$f_1(x_1,\dots x_n)=|x_{1}|+...+|x_{r}|$$ and $$f_2(x_1,\dots x_n)=2\left(\sqrt{x^{2}_{r+1}+x^{2}_{r+2}}+...\sqrt{x^{2}_{n-1}+x^{2}_{n}}\right).$$ Th check this, you could examine the Hessian matrices.

If $g$ is a convex function, then for any $a\in\Bbb R$ the *sublevel set* $\{x:g(x)\le a\}$ is convex. Indeed, if $g(x)\le a$ and $g(y)\le a$, then for $t\in[0,1]$ we have $$g\bigl(tx+(1-t)y\bigr)\le tg(x)+(1-t)g(y)\le ta+(1-t)a=a.$$